# Windows script to download and print a file ... suggestions?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've need to get a file from a remote (embedded) system (which I can do either by [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) or an ftp command) then print the contents of the file.

Once I've retrieved and printed the file I don't want to do it again.

It's a simple matter to make the embedded system publish a file that contains a number, or directory listing which the host system can use to determine if there is something 'new', but I'm completely clueless when it comes to scripting under Windows.

The host is Windows-7.

Suggestions?

Comment: I think using a combination of pscp.exe and psftp.exe will do the trick.  Once I've copied the file, I'm quite happy to have the host (actually client) delete it from the embedded system.  see: http://www.unix.com/windows-dos-issues-discussions/96371-can-we-delete-file-using-pscp.html

Comment: Do you want the shell script to send the file to a printer, or print it in some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using some of the excellent tools provided by Simon Tatham [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

The batch file was simply:

```
:START
pscp -q -batch -l root -pw root 10.0.2.67:/tmp/results2.txt c:/DX12/
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%" == "1" GOTO START
plink -l root -pw root 10.0.2.67 rm /tmp/results2.txt
```

The second part of the problem, printing was done by naming a printer share on the local machine and invoking a "net use" command to make the printer available to a command line ala LPT2:

Answer (score 0):

The low-tech solution would be batch files - just a list of instructions parseable by CMD.EXE. However, Windows gained a far more powerful scripting language, ["PowerShell"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx).

You obviously need to store local state somehow - if you don't remember what you printed, you can't implement this system at all.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to do it with [a batch file](http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm).

Comment: You may as well have suggested "Try programming something." for all the illumination you provided

Comment: I thought the batch file reference might get you started, but fair enough. Does MSalters not deserve a downvote for the same reason if you're in a vindictive mood?